# Nodejs: Attach Event Listener to Array If contains value

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

in my project I have four objects (connectors to HW decoders), which are obviously synchronous. And array (queue) of strings which I get to decryption. Is there anyway how to check if the array contains some values from Decoder objects? I think I can do it via EventEmitters, but I don't know how.

Thanks for help

**-Update**

Incoming value from another server is 64bites string, decoder returns 15 bites value. For communication via serial port I'm using this package [SerialPort](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport#module_serialport--SerialPort+close). I know how to the communication just with one decoder, but don't know how with more (in proper way).

My code for communication with one Decoder.

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var ports = [];
ports.push( {device: new SerialPort('/dev/cu.usbmodem1411', { autoOpen: false }), enable: true});
ports.push( {device: new SerialPort('/dev/cu.usbmodem1421', { autoOpen: false }), enable: true});


//id: incoming encrypted value
module.exports.decryption = function (id, callback) {

    ports[0].enable = false;
    var idArray = [];
    idArray[0] = id.slice(0, 16);
    idArray[1] = id.slice(16, 32);
    idArray[2] = id.slice(32, 48);
    idArray[3] = id.slice(48, 64);

    ports[0].device.open(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log('Error opening port: ', err.message);
        }
        port[0].device.write('d01');
        let index = 0;
        var buffer = setInterval(function () {
            port[0].device.write(idArray[index]);
            if (index === idArray.length - 1) clearInterval(buffer);
            index++;
        }, 1);

    });

    ports[0].device.on('data', function (data) {
        callback( hex2a(data.toString('ascii')));
        ports[0].device.close(function (response) {
            console.log("device disconnected")
        },function (error) {  });
        ports[0].enable = true;
    });
};

function hex2a(hexx) {
    var hex = hexx.toString();//force conversion
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2)
        str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
    return str;
}
```

Comment: I think your question would benefit from some code, in particular whatever definitions you can share about the decoder objects and array/queue. Plus any attempt(s) so far to solve the problem, no matter how incomplete or simplified.

Comment: @Will please do you have some solution?

Comment: To clarify, it seems you want to know two things: (1) how to setup with more than one decoder, and (2) how to check if you have already decoded a value in the array (presumably to save time by caching). Is that correct?

Comment: @Will yes, right.

Comment: @Will Users send encrypted value to the server, which has just to decoders. So I need to create queue, if users send to many request. For example server get 10 requests in same time so 8 request will be in queue before decoders can get next request.